# NodeJS MVC framework with partial ajax-loaded views

Tags: ajax, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js, partial

I'm looking for a NodeJS MVC framework that allows rendering partial views on client side using Ajax (without whole page refreshing).

As far as I know, you can declare partial views on server with almost any Framework (Express, Sails...), but this will lead to refresh the whole page even if there's only a small portion of your page that really changes. This problem doesn't exist with a SPA Framework (this one would just load the partial html file in a container via ajax).

I believe Microsoft ASP.NET MVC was able to handle this case, by comparing the previous version of the page with the new requested page, and just returning the portion of the page that really changed. This may be time and CPU-consuming but it just works.

Is any Node MVC Framework managing a similar thing today ? Or is it mandatory to use an SPA Framework when a reactive user interface is required (without any whole page refresh) ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/)! It supports partials as you requested. You don't need to refresh the page, if you send ajax-request or handle the stuff via websockets dynamically.

Comment: I didn't find any information about this in the documentation but if you say it works, then I'll try to investigate further. Thanks

Comment: E.g. http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers. Then, for example with jQuery, you call your controller with $.post/$.ajax.